# Highcharts-vue fails to update data/series

Tags: vue.js, highcharts

I'm trying to dynamically update data in highchairs. On the long term the idea is to have a dropdown list but for now I'm focusing on just having a button working properly.

https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-template-ub45g

It's a custom made graph so there's a lot of data going into the series.
So far, I have a file with the chart (i.e. Rose.vue), and an App.vue file. In the App.vue I have two variables (just as an example), original and updatedData. In theory if I would press the button, it should update the series to the updatedData. However, whenever I press it nothing happens.
The data is fine, as if I change the series manually in the code, the chart is updated. However, I'm not sure why the button isn't doing what it is supposed to do.

The code is below, but it's better to check the codesandbox example.

```
    <template>
  <div>
    <Rose v-bind:options="chart1"/>
    <button @click="updateChart()">Update chart</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Rose from "@/components/Rose";

export default {
  components: {
    Rose
  },
  data() {
    return {
      chart1: {
        title: {
          text: null
        },
        subtitle: {
          text: null
        },
        legend: {
          enabled: false
        },
        series: original.value
      }
    };
  },
  methods: {
    updateChart() {
      this.chart1.series = updatedData.value;
    }
  }
};

var original = {
  name: "Aalst",
  value: [
    {
      data: [10],
      type: "column",
      color: "#AEA8A8",
      name: "TESTMARK",
      pointStart: 0,
      pointRange: 0.5
    },
    {
      data: [1.99759968],
      type: "column",
      color: "#1DACE8",
      name: "S_N_AT_Park_tot",

      pointStart: 0,
      pointRange: 25.71
    },

    {
      data: [3.069066148],
      type: "column",
      color: "#1DACE8",
      name: "S_N_CA_Park_tot",

      pointStart: 25.71,
      pointRange: 25.71
    },

    {
      data: [4.762283492],
      type: "column",
      color: "#1DACE8",
      name: "S_N_BTM",

      pointStart: 51.42,
      pointRange: 25.71
    },

    {
      data: [10],
      type: "column",
      color: "#AEA8A8",
      name: "TESTMARK",
      pointStart: 77.13,
      pointRange: 0.5
    },

    {
      data: [5.472831225],
      type: "column",
      color: "#AEA8A8",
      name: "S_N_TR",
      pointStart: 77.13,
      pointRange: 25.71
    },
    {
      data: [10],
      type: "column",
      color: "#AEA8A8",
      name: "TESTMARK",
      pointStart: 102.84,
      pointRange: 0.5
    },

    {
      data: [5.089290648],
      type: "column",
      color: "#F24D29",
      name: "S_P_DE",

      pointStart: 102.84,
      pointRange: 25.71
    },

    {
      data: [8.593398356],
      type: "column",
      color: "#F24D29",
      name: "S_P_DI",

      pointStart: 128.55,
      pointRange: 25.71
    },

    {
      data: [5.06165564],
      type: "column",
      color: "#F24D29",
      name: "S_P_DG",

      pointStart: 154.26,
      pointRange: 25.74
    },

    {
      data: [10],
      type: "column",
      color: "#AEA8A8",
      name: "TESTMARK",
      pointStart: 180,
      pointRange: 0.5
    },

    {
      data: [3.63565202],
      type: "column",
      color: "#EDCB64",
      name: "S_PP_MOT_sec",

      pointStart: 180,
      pointRange: 19.2825
    },

    {
      data: [2.033564998],
      type: "column",
      color: "#EDCB64",
      name: "S_PP_MOT_tert",

      pointStart: 199.2825,
      pointRange: 19.2825
    },

    {
      data: [1.464012915],
      type: "column",
      color: "#EDCB64",
      name: "S_PP_MOT_work",

      pointStart: 218.465,
      pointRange: 19.2825
    },

    {
      data: [1.284840194],
      type: "column",
      color: "#EDCB64",
      name: "S_PP_MOT_other",

      pointStart: 237.6475,
      pointRange: 19.2825
    },

    {
      data: [10],
      type: "column",
      color: "#AEA8A8",
      name: "TESTMARK",
      pointStart: 256.83,
      pointRange: 0.5
    },

    {
      data: [5.840454632],
      type: "column",
      color: "#C4CFD0",
      name: "S_PP_RID_orig",

      pointStart: 256.83,
      pointRange: 8.57
    },

    {
      data: [1.153663761],
      type: "column",
      color: "#C4CFD0",
      name: "S_PP_RID_rid",

      pointStart: 265.4,
      pointRange: 8.57
    },

    {
      data: [4.159545368],
      type: "column",
      color: "#C4CFD0",
      name: "S_PP_RID_dest",

      pointStart: 273.97,
      pointRange: 8.57
    },

    {
      data: [10],
      type: "column",
      color: "#AEA8A8",
      name: "TESTMARK",
      pointStart: 282.54,
      pointRange: 0.5
    },

    {
      data: [1.283496592],
      type: "column",
      color: "#76A08A",
      name: "S_PP_EFF_walk",

      pointStart: 282.54,
      pointRange: 25.71
    },

    {
      data: [4.765886288],
      type: "column",
      color: "#76A08A",
      name: "S_PP_EFF_bike",

      pointStart: 308.25,
      pointRange: 25.71
    },

    {
      data: [4.72029121],
      type: "column",
      color: "#76A08A",
      name: "S_PP_EFF_far",

      pointStart: 333.96,
      pointRange: 26.04
    }
  ]
};

var updatedData = {
  name: "Anzegem",
  value: [
    {
      data: [10],
      type: "column",
      color: "#AEA8A8",
      name: "TESTMARK",
      pointStart: 0,
      pointRange: 0.5
    },
    {
      data: [0.128017069],
      type: "column",
      color: "#1DACE8",
      name: "S_N_AT_Park_tot",

      pointStart: 0,
      pointRange: 25.71
    },

    {
      data: [0.403696498],
      type: "column",
      color: "#1DACE8",
      name: "S_N_CA_Park_tot",

      pointStart: 25.71,
      pointRange: 25.71
    },

    {
      data: [0.253077371],
      type: "column",
      color: "#1DACE8",
      name: "S_N_BTM",

      pointStart: 51.42,
      pointRange: 25.71
    },

    {
      data: [10],
      type: "column",
      color: "#AEA8A8",
      name: "TESTMARK",
      pointStart: 77.13,
      pointRange: 0.5
    },

    {
      data: [3.734963849],
      type: "column",
      color: "#AEA8A8",
      name: "S_N_TR",
      pointStart: 77.13,
      pointRange: 25.71
    },
    {
      data: [10],
      type: "column",
      color: "#AEA8A8",
      name: "TESTMARK",
      pointStart: 102.84,
      pointRange: 0.5
    },

    {
      data: [0.867670432],
      type: "column",
      color: "#F24D29",
      name: "S_P_DE",

      pointStart: 102.84,
      pointRange: 25.71
    },

    {
      data: [3.47744926],
      type: "column",
      color: "#F24D29",
      name: "S_P_DI",

      pointStart: 128.55,
      pointRange: 25.71
    },

    {
      data: [0.994857797],
      type: "column",
      color: "#F24D29",
      name: "S_P_DG",

      pointStart: 154.26,
      pointRange: 25.74
    },

    {
      data: [10],
      type: "column",
      color: "#AEA8A8",
      name: "TESTMARK",
      pointStart: 180,
      pointRange: 0.5
    },

    {
      data: [0],
      type: "column",
      color: "#EDCB64",
      name: "S_PP_MOT_sec",

      pointStart: 180,
      pointRange: 19.2825
    },

    {
      data: [0],
      type: "column",
      color: "#EDCB64",
      name: "S_PP_MOT_tert",

      pointStart: 199.2825,
      pointRange: 19.2825
    },

    {
      data: [0.36406198],
      type: "column",
      color: "#EDCB64",
      name: "S_PP_MOT_work",

      pointStart: 218.465,
      pointRange: 19.2825
    },

    {
      data: [0.748181912],
      type: "column",
      color: "#EDCB64",
      name: "S_PP_MOT_other",

      pointStart: 237.6475,
      pointRange: 19.2825
    },

    {
      data: [10],
      type: "column",
      color: "#AEA8A8",
      name: "TESTMARK",
      pointStart: 256.83,
      pointRange: 0.5
    },

    {
      data: [9.28512162],
      type: "column",
      color: "#C4CFD0",
      name: "S_PP_RID_orig",

      pointStart: 256.83,
      pointRange: 8.57
    },

    {
      data: [0.027799127],
      type: "column",
      color: "#C4CFD0",
      name: "S_PP_RID_rid",

      pointStart: 265.4,
      pointRange: 8.57
    },

    {
      data: [0.71487838],
      type: "column",
      color: "#C4CFD0",
      name: "S_PP_RID_dest",

      pointStart: 273.97,
      pointRange: 8.57
    },

    {
      data: [10],
      type: "column",
      color: "#AEA8A8",
      name: "TESTMARK",
      pointStart: 282.54,
      pointRange: 0.5
    },

    {
      data: [1.393719008],
      type: "column",
      color: "#76A08A",
      name: "S_PP_EFF_walk",

      pointStart: 282.54,
      pointRange: 25.71
    },

    {
      data: [5.832167832],
      type: "column",
      color: "#76A08A",
      name: "S_PP_EFF_bike",

      pointStart: 308.25,
      pointRange: 25.71
    },

    {
      data: [3.685239492],
      type: "column",
      color: "#76A08A",
      name: "S_PP_EFF_far",

      pointStart: 333.96,
      pointRange: 26.04
    }
  ]
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to make it using `events`. The event will be emitted in the App component with new data and received in the Rose component that will change the chartOptions.

**App.vue:**

```
  methods: {
    updateChart() {
      EventBus.$emit("btn-clicked", {
        newData: updatedData.value
      });
    }
  }
```

**Rose.vue:**

```
  created() {
    EventBus.$on("btn-clicked", data => {
      this.chartOptions.series = data.newData;
    });
  }
```

**Demo:**

- https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-template-tf0d8